# Can we use OAuth to get notifications on behalf of customer salesforce accounts if they don't have workflow functionality?

Tags: oauth2, workflowoutboundmessage, streaming-api, notification, push

We're building an application that integrates with Salesforce. As part of this, we expect users to give us OAuth permission to learn about events involving their Salesforce accounts. We'd rather use a push approach than have to poll constantly. However, it appears that Outbound Messaging requires Workflow rules, which imply Enterprise Edition.

If we have Enterprise Edition developer accounts but the customer only has Professional edition, can Outbound Messaging be used? Logic says no, but we wanted to make sure we're not missing something.

The Streaming API appears to be nonviable because it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the only reasonable attempt you'd have is to try and describe the metadata in the org and see if workflows appear, or even better, try to create a new rule and see if it fails (you can always delete it later). I'm pretty sure you can "add on" workflow rules to Professional Edition, depending on whom you talk to, so the easiest way is probably by workflow. Note that if you don't have workflow, you also won't have many other formal techniques, like triggers, so you may well be stuck with replication APIs if all else fails.